# Make card inside div scrollable in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I achieve a scrollable card in Bootstrap 4 when I have the following html structure:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    ....
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      ...
    </nav>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy Policy</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The sidebar is at the left of the screen, the wrapper has a `display: flex` to achieve this. What I want is that the `.sidebar` won't scroll when the content overflows the `#content`'s height. In other words, only `.card` should be scrollable, but not `#content`.

Comment: just add height to card class and set overflow-x to scroll

Comment: When I set height: 100% and overflow-y: scroll on the card, nothing happens. The wrapper still expands vertically if the content of the card doesn't fit inside it.

Comment: set height like 350px etc and give overflow-x to scroll

Comment: so u r making the card to occupy the full height of the page i'm right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following styles

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#content .card {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px); /* Total height - heinght of the navbar*/
}
```

This is similar to the implementation of sidebar on bootstrap's website.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#content .card {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  /* Total height - heinght of the navbar*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/>Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/>    Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/> Sidebar <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      ...
    </nav>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy Policy</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked by using calc(100vh - 150px). Dunno why it's so large, but it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the following in your CSS Stylesheet?

```
.wrapper #content .card{
overflow-y: scroll;}
```

This will set a scroll property in the y-direction only to the selected card. Alternatively, you can use : `<div class="card" style="overflow-y: scroll;">`

Answer (score 0):

set `overflow-y` property to `auto`. You can also provide `max-height` to contain the card div

```
style="max-height: 100px; overflow-y:auto"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    ....
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      ...
    </nav>
    <div class="card" style="max-height: 100px; overflow-y:auto">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Privacy Policy</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```